# eventReceive: return a null for event end when dropped on weekly calendar

Tags: null, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar example code external-dragging-builtin.html
I've only added the eventReceive parm.
Alerting the event title and start returns data. end is null.
I put the code up on codepen for your review.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
 eventReceive: function(info) {
        alert(info.event.title);
        alert(info.event.start);
        alert(info.event.end);
 https://codepen.io/drinkingwine/pen/PoPmeEx?editors=0010
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is weird. After several hours of playing with this code on codepen...it's working.
I have no idea why, but it's working as advertised.

I was in IT for 26 years on mainframes...my debugging skills must be getting rusty...

Answer (score 0):

it was probably missing the `forceEventDuration: true` in the calendar

> https://fullcalendar.io/docs/forceEventDuration

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).